# How to take off invalid values inside a CUDA array

Tags: cuda

I'm find it hard to design a **parallel** method who shall do condition partitioning in CUDA arrays.

I'm given three arrays, 1st and 2nd array include numbers and 3rd boolean array include the status for each index in 1st and 2nd arrays.

I'd like to exclude the invalid data points from the 1st and 2nd array, at the end store the valid and invalid points on separate arrays.

Unfortunately, the order between the 1st and 2nd array values is matter, e.g: a[i] is related to b[i]. However the order between adjacent values doesn't matter.

I don't mind using latest CUDA libraries, extensions libraries or trust, I can't find how to implement such method in a high standard parallel way.

An example given:

```
int a[9] =       {5, 9 , 3, 2, 7 ,4  ,6  , 24, 1 };
int b [9] =      {7, 4 , 5, 2, 9 ,10 , 45, 67, 12}; 
bool isValid[9]= {t, f , t, t, t ,f  , f , t,  t };

// I'd like to get the output 

int a[] =       {5, 3, 2, 7 ,24, 1 };
int b [] =      {7, 5, 2, 9 ,67, 12}; 
bool isValid[]= {t, t, t, t , t,  t };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parallel primitive you are looking for is known as stream compaction, and there are a lot of stream compaction implementations in read-to-go libraries.

For example, thrust includes two different [stream compaction](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#gaf01d45b30fecba794afae065d625f94f) operations, `copy_if` and `remove_if`, which could be used for your purpose. The excellent CUB library includes [DeviceSelect](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_select.html) which also performs stream compaction. The DPP library also includes stream compaction routines. I am sure one of those could be adapted to your problem according to your tastes.